# cudaMemcpyFromSymbol errors when calling a CUDA kernel multiple times

Tags: cuda

I am running a loop on a GPU such that after every iteration, I check if the convergence condition is satisified. If yes, I exit the while loop.

```
__device__ int converged = 0; // this line before the kernel
```

inside the kernel:

```
__global__ convergence_kernel()
{
   if (convergence condition is true)
   {
      atomicAdd(&converged, 1);
   }
}
```

On CPU I am calling the kernel within the loop:

```
int *convc = (int*) calloc(1,sizeof(int));
//converged = 0; //commenting as this is not correct as per Robert's suggestion
while(convc[0]< 1)
{
    foo_bar1<<<num_blocks, threads>>>(err, count);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    count += 1;

    cudaMemcpyFromSymbol(convc, converged, sizeof(int));
}
```

So here, if the condition is true, my convc[0] = 1, however, when I print this value, I always see a random value, eg. conv = 3104 , conv = 17280, conv = 17408, etc.

Can someone tell me what's missing in my `cudaMemcpyFromSymbol` operation? Am I missing something?? Thanks in advance.

Comment: cuda-memcheck passes with no errors !

Comment: do you ever initialize the `converged` `__device__` variable?  You certainly can't do it with `converged = 0;` in CPU code.

Comment: What do you think `converged = 0` does in your host code?

Comment: @talonmies if `converged = 0` then the kernel foo_bar1 is called again. @robert-crovella how does one initialize the device variable?

Comment: Of course you have no statement that looks like this:  `if (converged = 0) ...;` which would be broken anyway, so saying "if `converged = 0` then the kernel foo_bar1 is called again" makes no sense and is inconsistent with the code you have shown.  The code you have shown is pretty much incoherent.  To initialize a `__device__` variable, one method is to use the [`cudaMemcpyToSymbol` function](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__MEMORY.html#group__CUDART__MEMORY_1g2a229a704ade54887f7784e2e2dbd895).  You can also statically initialize it: `__device__ int converged = 0;`

Answer (score 1):

My best guess as to why you are getting garbage when you read the `converged` value into `convc` is that you have not initialized `converged` anywhere.   It can't be done in host code like this:

```
converged = 0;
```

You could change your declaration to be like this:

```
__device__ int converged = 0; // this line before the kernel
```

or you could also use the `cudaMemcpyToSymbol` [function](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__MEMORY.html#group__CUDART__MEMORY_1g2a229a704ade54887f7784e2e2dbd895), which is effectively the reverse of the `cudaMemcpyFromSymbol` function that you already seem to be aware of.

Comment: I have initialized the device variable to 0 in the kernel. Still I see this error. My flags are: `NVCCFLAGS   = -O3 -use_fast_math -m64 --ptxas-options=-v -lineinfo` and `GENCODE_SM20    := -gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_20
GENCODE_SM30    := -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30 -gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35
GENCODE_FLAGS   := $(GENCODE_SM30)`

Comment: then I suggest providing a short, complete, compilable code that reproduces the issue.  You should also add [proper cuda error checking](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038589/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-errors-using-the-cuda-runtime-api) and run your code with `cuda-memcheck`.